# How to store sql query in variable

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

```
SELECT Staff_Teaching.TeachingID FROM   Staff_Teaching INNER JOIN
          Staff ON Staff_Teaching.StaffID = Staff.StaffID WHERE        (Staff.StaffID = @StaffID) AND (Staff_Teaching.SemesterID = @SemesterID))
```

I have this query which return the staff TeachingID which is an id for the courses that the staff teaches.

My question is :

1. How to store these values because it returns MORE THAN 1 values , can I use array in sql server or in c# ?
2. Then I want to take theses value and pass it to other query as shown below :

(SELECT Exam.Date  FROM Exam WHERE (ExamID = @GetExamID)

```
`@GetExamID` is where I want to pass these values to be checked
```

can I use foreach or array? and I am using asp.net (C#)

This is what I am trying to do

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @GetTeachingID =(SELECT        Staff_Teaching.TeachingID
FROM          Staff_Teaching INNER JOIN
              Staff ON Staff_Teaching.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
WHERE        (Staff.StaffID = @StaffID) AND (Staff_Teaching.SemesterID = @SemesterID))
COMMIT 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT  Course_Department.CourseID
FROM            Course_Department INNER JOIN
                         Exam ON Course_Department.CourseID = Exam.ExamID INNER JOIN
                         ExamSchedule ON Exam.ExamID = ExamSchedule.ExamID INNER JOIN
                         Staff_Teaching ON Course_Department.TeachingID = Staff_Teaching.TeachingID
WHERE        (Staff_Teaching.TeachingID = @GetTeachingID)

COMMIT 


BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @GetExamDate=(SELECT Exam.Date  
FROM Exam
WHERE (ExamID = @GetExamID))
COMMIT 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @GetExamTime=(SELECT Exam.BegainTime  
FROM Exam
WHERE (ExamID = @GetExamID))
COMMIT 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT        ExamScheduleID
FROM          Exam INNER JOIN
              ExamSchedule ON Exam.ExamID = ExamSchedule.ExamID
WHERE        (ExamSchedule.ExamScheduleID = @ExamScheduleID) AND (Exam.Date LIKE @GetExamDate) AND (Exam.BegainTime<=@GetExamTime)
COMMIT 



END
```

I have 5 query the first one will get the teachingid (1 Value)
the second will get the coursesid (More than 1 value)
then next two will take coursesid and get the exam date and time 
then l want to check if there are any result in the last query

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately.  Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Is Exam table have TeachingID column

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like array in SQL Server. You can use #temp table to store this temporarily.

```
SELECT Staff_Teaching.TeachingID
INTO #Temp
Staff_Teaching INNER JOIN
      Staff ON Staff_Teaching.StaffID = Staff.StaffID WHERE                    
     (Staff.StaffID = @StaffID) AND (Staff_Teaching.SemesterID = @SemesterID))
```

[Temporary tables](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server)

Pass it as

```
SELECT Exam.Date  FROM Exam WHERE (ExamID IN SELECT * FROM #Temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it as

```
declare @query = '(SELECT Exam.Date  FROM Exam WHERE (ExamID IN ('+@GetExamID+') )'

exec @query
```

and pass @GetExamID from C# as comma separated string 1,2,4,5,......

You can convert array of int to comma separated string  using the following

```
var result = string.Join(",", arr);
```

Comment: How will I save the values in the first query to pass it to  @GetExamID ?!